# How to change the search box in Magento 2.2.4?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.4

[image]

I tried to move the search box to right and all categories to left. But where can i find the code in Magento 2.2.4 .

Please check the above image

Comment: enable path hints there you will find the template file